# Animate the top edge of a DIV

Tags: jquery

I've been looking for a solution to animate the width of the top edge of a DIV using jQuery. I want to keep the bottom edge of the DIV(eg, 100px X 100px) the same but reduce the width of the top edge. The eventual shape will be a trapezoid. Does anyone know how this can be done? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIVs are block level elements. You can't change the shape like that unless you use border radius (even then I don't think you can get it to be a trapezoid) or some CSS3 trick (which won't be supported in all elements)

Here's a list of CSS3 effects you can use : http://www.css3.info/preview/

Comment: Thanks JohnP. I will check out CSS3 effects.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I thought of 2 better, easier, and smarter ways of doing what you want.

here's an example using one div:
http://jsfiddle.net/reveries/ntgCL/

```
#box {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: black;
position: relative;
}
#box:after, #box:before {
display: block;
content:"\0020";
color: transparent;
width: 211px;
height: 45px;
background: white;
position: absolute;
left: 1px;
bottom: -20px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-12deg);
}
#box:before {
bottom: auto;
top: -20px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(12deg);
}
```

and a second solution using two divs (much more control here in my opinion): http://jsfiddle.net/reveries/2gRMh/

```
#right {
width: 120px;
height: 200px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
left:130px;
transform:skew(-10deg,0deg);
-ms-transform:skew(-10deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:skew(-10deg,0deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:skew(-10deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:skew(-10deg,0deg); /* Opera */
}

#left {
width: 120px;
height: 200px;
background: black;
position: absolute;
left:200px;
transform:skew(10deg,0deg);
-ms-transform:skew(10deg,0deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:skew(10deg,0deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:skew(10deg,0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:skew(10deg,0deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get edge animate from adobe (it's free) https://creative.adobe.com/ you have to make a creative cloud account then go to apps and it's the full program for free.

Watch some tutorials and get familiar with the interface, then what's below might make more sense.

One thing I've done (but which takes a while to load on slower machines) is pre-rendered out a series of images, you can use photoshop, or illustrator, or even 3D software... Then if you load all the images into edge, you can animate the opacity for each image and scale the timeline down or up to control the frame rate.

Here's an example: 
http://www.reveriesrefined.com/myftp/door/

This example uses 41 frames, however for turning a square into a trapezoid, you could get away with maybe 5-10 frames (maybe even less).